# Create array of n objects (UILabel) and map them with another array of String

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

I'm facing two problems. I want to create an array of `UILabel`.
I tried:

`private var weekdayLabels = [DayLabel](repeating: DayLabel(), count: 7)`,
but it uses the same instance of `DayLabel()`.

I ended up using this other, much uglier solution:

```
(0...6).forEach { _ in
        weekdayLabels.append(DayLabel())
}
```

Is there a way I can make `[DayLabel](repeating: DayLabel(), count: 7)` work?

The second problem comes while mapping an array of `String` with the weekday names to my array of `[UILabel]` :

```
weekdayLabels.enumerated().forEach {
        $0.element.text = weekdayNames[$0.offset]
}
```

I believe there must be a better way to map the `String` to the `UILabel().text`. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Array(repeating:count:)` really means repeating. The expression for the `repeating` argument is only evaluated once. Use `(0..<count).map` instead.
2. Ue `zip` to pair each label to the corresponding string.

The code:

```
weekDayLabels = (0..<7).map { _ in DayLabel() }

let weekDayNames = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
zip(weekDayLabels, weekDayNames).forEach { label, dayName in
    label.text = dayName
}
```

Comment: And even more beautiful as a one-liner: `zip(weekdayLabels, weekdayNames).forEach { $0.text = $1 }`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that's a shorter way to write it. But the older I get, the more I prefer meaningful variable names. Nothing but personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring your weekdayLabels array as a `private lazy var`?

I've had problems in the past with declaring arrays of other UIKit objects (assuming because they may or may not have been instantiated yet by the storyboard) and had to resort to the following to access the state of a `ToggleButton` (a custom, toggle-able `UIButton` implementation) in an optional array of buttons:

```
lazy var buttonsArray = {
    [buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree]
}()

...

if buttonsArray[index]?.isOn == true {
        buttonsArray[index]?.buttonPressed()
}
```

Comment: I guess this works if you have already initialised buttonOne, buttonTwo, etc.
In my case I want to initialise them "on the go".